# Android BLE permissions

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, bluetooth-lowenergy

[Google Translated]

The app works with BLE devices. I debugged it on Android 10 and everything worked fine. I decided to check for 8.0 and found that the search was not working. Judging by the logs, most likely it's a matter of permission, but I can't find the error.

P.S. The [code](https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleBluetoothLeTerminal) is partially not mine, so I would be grateful if there is a detailed explanation.

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**Code:**

```
    public void startScan() {

    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        checkBluetoothState();
        return;
    }
    /*
    PERMISSIONS_CHECK
     */
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            scanState = ScanState.NONE;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.location_permission_title);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.location_permission_message);
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    (dialog, which) -> requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0));
            builder.show();
            return;
        }
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationEnabled = false;
        try {
            locationEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch(Exception ignored) {}
        try {
            locationEnabled |= locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch(Exception ignored) {}
        if(!locationEnabled)
            scanState = ScanState.DISCOVERY;
        // Starting with Android 6.0 a bluetooth scan requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission, but that's not all!
        // LESCAN also needs enabled 'location services', whereas DISCOVERY works without.
        // Most users think of GPS as 'location service', but it includes more, as we see here.
        // Instead of asking the user to enable something they consider unrelated,
        // we fall back to the older API that scans for bluetooth classic _and_ LE
        // sometimes the older API returns less results or slower
    }

    if (!locationEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    if(scanState != ScanState.NONE)
        return;
    scanState = ScanState.LESCAN;

    listItems.clear();
    foundListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    tvNoDeviceFound.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if(scanState == ScanState.LESCAN) {
        leScanStopHandler.postDelayed(this::stopScan, LESCAN_PERIOD);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(null,leScanCallback);
                Log.d(TAG, "starLetScan: scanning");
                return null;

            }
        }.execute();// start async to prevent blocking UI, because startLeScan sometimes take some seconds
    } else {
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
    if(scanState == ScanState.LESCAN) {
        pbSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            // ignore requestCode as there is only one in this fragment
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               startScan();
               locationEnabled = true;
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0])) {
    
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.location_permission_title);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.location_permission_message_clarification);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.location_permission_go_to_settings, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                            Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                });
                builder.show();
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle(getText(R.string.location_denied_title));
                builder.setMessage(getText(R.string.location_denied_message));
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gps is activated on the phone? a reading at the official doc could help you ([Android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le)).

In one of my app I use the BluetoothLeScannerCompat ([BluetoothLeScannerCompat](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library)) and it works fine both with android 10 android 8.0

I show you a utils class that I use to show all the necessary permissions (might help you solve)

```java
public class PermissionUtils {
    public static void askForPermissions(Activity activity) {
        List<String> permissionsToAsk = new ArrayList<>();
        int requestResult = 0;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Ask for permission
            permissionsToAsk.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Ask for permission
            permissionsToAsk.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Ask for permission
            permissionsToAsk.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Ask for permission
            permissionsToAsk.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

        if (permissionsToAsk.size() > 0) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissionsToAsk.toArray(new String[permissionsToAsk.size()]), requestResult);
        }
    }
}
```

And try to add all of these on manifest:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Location data has been disabled on the device. And apparently, my application does not ask the user to enable this parameter, but only asks permission to receive data. It turns out that I need to add a request to include geodata in addition to receiving data from them.